# Mocking values in TDD

Tags: java, oop, tdd

In the book [GOOS](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/). It is told [not to mock values](http://www.mockobjects.com/2007/04/test-smell-everything-is-mocked.html), which leaves me confused. Does it means that values don't have any behavior?

I dont' much knowledge about the value object but AFAIK the value objects are those which are immutable. Is there any heuristic on deciding when to create a value object?

Comment: Mockito says the same here: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-value-objects

Comment: I've added a link to a blog post by the book's authors, for the benefit of us who don't have a copy of the book to hand.

Comment: I think that the point that they are trying to make is that mocking a value can be more complicated than just using the value's actual behaviour e.g. `Point point = mock(Point.class); when(point.getX()).thenReturn(1); when(point.getY()).thenReturn(2);` vs `Point point = new Point(1, 2);`.

Comment: Hmm, but what is the value object has some behavior too for eg: `isInThirdCoordinate`. The example is too shallow but might get my point.

Comment: Value objects don't really have behaviour, they are things which are logically like numbers, points, postal addresses etc. You might want to have a method on your value like `PostalAddress.getFormattedAddress()`, but that's really just going to be doing something like concatenating the fields - you don't need to provide an alternative arbitrary implementation for that, since you have a perfectly good implementation already.

Comment: So, that simple behavior need not be tested? also, if there is a need to add some complex behavior then I should think of adding a service object on top of it?

Comment: The simple behaviour should be tested, but in the unit tests of the value class; you shouldn't be testing the value class' behaviour in tests for other classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all immutable objects are value objects. By the way, when designing, consider that the ideal object has only immutable fields and no-arg methods.

Regarding the heuristic, a valid approach can be considering how objects will be used: if you build an instance, invoke some methods and then are done with it (or store it in a field) likely it won't be a value object. On the contrary, if you keep objects in some data structure and compare them (with `.equals()`) likely you have a *value object*. This is especially true for objects that will be used to key `Map`s

Value objects should be automatic-tested themselves (and tests are usually a pleasure to read and write because are straightforward) but there's no point in mocking them: the main practical reasons for mocking interfaces is that implementation classes

- are usually difficult to build (need lot of collaborators)
- are expensive to run (access the network, the filesystem, ...).

Neither apply to value objects.

Comment: +1. I'd add a third point: practically mocking those objects can be difficult and error-prone. For a mutable value object, it may not easy to stub that `getX` should return 5 until after `setX(10)`, at which point `getX` should return 10. If you're looking for an existing, well-tested object that implements that behavior, your value object should be much safer and easier than a test double.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [linked blog post](http://www.mockobjects.com/2007/04/test-smell-everything-is-mocked.html):

> There are a couple of heuristics for when a class is not worth mocking. First, it has only accessors or simple methods that act on values it holds, it doesn't have any interesting behaviour. Second, you can't think of a meaningful name for the class other than VideoImpl or some such vague term.

The implication of the first point, in the context of a section entitled "Don't mock value objects", is that value objects don't have interesting behaviour.