# Mockito discourages mocking VO and DTOs ? A good reason why

Tags: mockito

We have complex VO objects in our domain. Sometimes an update to VO may be something like:

```
SampleDomain domain = new SampleDomain(Object type, String name, Object
detailType,....., int newfieldInDomain);
```

Now we please note it is not a simple VO. Suppose the building block of the VO changes and I just want to check that part of the change there are 2 options :

1. Update the builder/factory and use it in everyTest
2. Mock the objectTypes and just see if the new element has been set in the 
   Object

What could the reasons why we should avoid mocking this or what are the pitfalls of mocking it ?

Comment: Good question, but I think this existing Q&A covers the bases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34674313/mocking-values-in-tdd

Comment: Alright. Thanks Jeff. I like the explanation from you "For a mutable value object, it may not easy to stub that getX should return 5 until after setX(10), at which point getX should return 10. If you're looking for an existing, well-tested object that implements that behavior, your value object should be much safer and easier than a test double" . The challenge is to convince fellow developers as they usually resort to shortcuts and easy to test and misuse Mockito